# jquery show hide multiple div fastest way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello How can Possible to

Work with show or hide multiple div

The fastest way possible

Why do I need to number each div

like this : 

open,close,show_text

open2,close2,show_text2

I wish that it will be repeated for each div 10 times

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").click(function(){
        $(".show_text").show('blind');
  $(".open").hide();
  $(".close").show();
    });
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".open").show();
  $(".show_text").hide('blind');
  $(".close").hide();
    });
});  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open2").click(function(){
        $(".show_text2").show('blind');
  $(".open2").hide();
  $(".close2").show();
    });
    $(".close2").click(function(){
        $(".open2").show();
  $(".show_text2").hide('blind');
  $(".close2").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open" style="cursor:pointer">Open 1
</div><!-- open -->
<div class="close" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;">Close 1
</div><!-- close -->
<div class="show_text" style="display:none;">
hello world 1
</div><!-- show_text -->

<div class="open2" style="cursor:pointer">Open 2
</div><!-- open -->
<div class="close2" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;">Close 2
</div><!-- close -->
<div class="show_text2" style="display:none;">
hello world 2
</div><!-- show_text -->
```

Comment: I think assigning id's to divs will speed up your dom selection to some extend, for further speed use pure js. Compare at https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you content in a container div, then you can use

1. [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

2. [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

*HTML*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="open" style="cursor:pointer">Open 1
    </div>
    <!-- open -->
    <div class="close" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;">Close 1
    </div>
    <!-- close -->
    <div class="show_text" style="display:none;">
    hello world 1
    </div>
</div>
```

*Code*

```
$(".open").click(function() {
    //Traverse up to container div
    var container = $(this).closest('.container'); 

    //Use .find() to find child
});
```

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open").click(function() {
    var continer = $(this).closest('.container');
    continer.find(".show_text").show('blind');
    continer.find(".open").hide();
    continer.find(".close").show();
  });
  $(".close").click(function() {
    var continer = $(this).closest('.container');
    continer.find(".open").show();
    continer.find(".show_text").hide('blind');
    continer.find(".close").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="open" style="cursor:pointer">Open 1
  </div>
  <!-- open -->
  <div class="close" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;">Close 1
  </div>
  <!-- close -->
  <div class="show_text" style="display:none;">
    hello world 1
  </div>
</div>
<!-- show_text -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="open" style="cursor:pointer">Open 2
  </div>
  <!-- open -->
  <div class="close" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;">Close 2
  </div>
  <!-- close -->
  <div class="show_text" style="display:none;">
    hello world 2
  </div>
</div>
<!-- show_text -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[class^=open]").click(function(){
        $("div[class^=show_text]").show('blind');
  $("div[class^=open]").hide();
  $("div[class^=close]").show();
    });
    $("div[class^=close]").click(function(){
        $("div[class^=open]").show();
  $("div[class^=show_text]").hide('blind');
  $("div[class^=close]").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open" style="cursor:pointer">Open 1
</div><!-- open -->
<div class="close" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;">Close 1
</div><!-- close -->
<div class="show_text" style="display:none;">
hello world 1
</div><!-- show_text -->

<div class="open2" style="cursor:pointer">Open 2
</div><!-- open -->
<div class="close2" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;">Close 2
</div><!-- close -->
<div class="show_text2" style="display:none;">
hello world 2
</div><!-- show_text -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you have provided, if you haven't figured this out yet, I think that the most efficient way to accomplish this task is by using a loop (of some sort). In my mind this would make the most sense if your goal is speed. That being said, I think that attempting to do this with jQuery's show() & hide() will only hold you back.

If you want to "number" each  element, and display them at different times, depending on certain circumstances, think JSON; JavaScript's older and more attractive brother. I'm happy to assist you further if need be, else, cheers.